# Stop HTML5 audio in UIPageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiwebview, html5-audio, uipageviewcontroller

I have an array of webView loaded in UIPageviewController. Each webView will load a HTML page with audio or video. The problem that i m facing is the audio keeps playing when i navigate to the next page. How can we stop the audio when navigating to the next page in PageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

load a blank page before dismissing the view:

```
[self.webContent loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")];
```

Comment: Hi Retro thanks for the reply. One small clarification. Do I have to add this in UIPageviewController's willTransitionToViewControllers, please let me know.